# Should I delete answer that is a hack

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

An answer I posted for [tikz fit library vs fill overlaying nested node colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41938/4301) only accidentally appeared to work and thanks to Jake it was noticed. I adjusted it to **make** it work, but an labelled it as a hack solution. So wondering if I should delete this answer?

Personally I find I can learn by seeing things that don't work almost as much as things that work.  I do recall previously reversing the order of some nodes and getting the result I wanted, but obviously it did not involve using the `fit` library.  However, since I have enough rep to see this non-answer, even after it is deleted, all is good for me. Just wondering if others think that it won't be on any value, or even cause confusion to people learning from the solutions posted.

So, I am soliciting opinions on whether I should delete this or leave it?

Comment: If I deleted all of my hacky answers, I'd have none left!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if the "accidental" solution is something that a lot of people might think of, only to find out after a lot of effort that it doesn't really work, it might be worth keeping, clearly labeled as bogus -- "do not try this at home".

but if it's not at all obvious, and would only be *found* with a lot of effort, then i'd most likely delete it, so as not to mislead.  (in fact, i've done just that.)

the real goal in such a case should be "do not mislead".